# Parsing of XML ServletContext resource BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: java, xml, spring

I know sililar question ask many time but I don't understand what wrong. Help me fix this.  I try to run my app with SpringMVC but I get:

> 11-Aug-2017 13:06:29.471 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource

I set file path in `web.xml` `classpath:spring-context.xml`:

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Process application servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of your web xml you declared `ContextLoaderListener`. 
As you can see in this document
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html#ContextLoaderListener--
when you use the default constructor (without parameters)  it act as follow

> Create a new ContextLoaderListener that will create a web application
>   context based on the "contextClass" and "contextConfigLocation"
>   servlet context-params.

The default `contextConfigLocation` is exactally `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. In your project that file doesn't exist, but is needed by the class `ContextLoaderListener` wich look for that and, when don't find it, throw the exception you mention.
You can solve your issue by pasing your config as param.

Comment: what are You mean _pasing as param_?

Comment: using the tag param-name and param-value topass the parameters to the constructor of ContextConfig Location